# jquery count to number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that counts from 0 to a specified number with a specified delay.

The problem is that it adds by 1 and I want it to add by 0.01

How to do it? the code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>body{font:11px verdana;color:#555;}</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var max = 20;// set with php
$(incCounter);
function incCounter() {
    var currCount = parseInt($('.counter').html());
    $('.counter').text(currCount+1);
    if (currCount+1 != max) {
        setTimeout(incCounter,50);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="counter">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It surely cannot be as simple as `$('.counter').text(currCount + 0.01)`, right?

Comment: have you tried num.toFixed(2)

Comment: Did you try running that function, and not just wrapping it ?

Comment: @adeneo sure I have a test page and trying to test every suggestion

Comment: What result? What exactly doesn't work with @slashingweapon answer? And, as a sidenote, do you know that each time someone reports a 'does not work' bug into the public (instead of just DESCRIBING what the h doesn't work), a cute kitten cringes in pain somewhere?

Comment: sorry @slashingweapon but when I tested the suggestion I got the same result like that of the original code. This code is complete and works right, but I just want it to add by 0.01 and not a whole 1. anyone can test the code, just cut/paste in a blank html page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but try...

```
function incCounter() {
    var currCount = parseFloat($('.counter').html());
    currCount += .01;
    $('.counter').text( currCount.toFixed(2) );
    if (currCount < max)
        setTimeout(incCounter,50);
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPhmN/) to play with.

Comment: Altough it's against my policy to upvote answers for trivial programming tasks, still +1 - quite a nice implementation. ) Will add a fiddle for that.

Comment: +1 because you beat my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashingweapon/mWAgu/) by a whole 7 minutes.